How can I use the GitHub login in Visual Studio to access the GitHub APIs through a custom Visual Studio extension?
I am currently using Azure Devops Server (on-prem) with a custom Visual Studio extension that simplifies remote branch management and pull request management via the Azure Devops API and integrated authentication.
We are investigating moving to GitHub Enterprise (cloud) and are having trouble figuring out any way to maintain this functionality without having to manually enter a token in the configuration and then figure out some way to securely store it.
Ideally, we'd like to be able to use the built in keychain functionality that Visual Studio has for holding a GitHub Enterprise login and use that account for requesting remote branch management and pull request creation, but I can't find anyway to access this information in a usable way from our custom Visual Studio extension.
What is the best way to access the GitHub Enterprise APIs from a custom Visual Studio extension in a secure manner?

I think github apps should suitable for your situation, you can take a look at my answer.

GitHub supports several methods for authenticating API requests:

Personal Access Tokens (PATs)
OAuth Apps
GitHub Apps

I think the Github Apps method should be suitable for your situation. Access tokens are short lived and each GitHub App operates independently, so it’s isolated from the user’s personal GitHub account.

Unfortunately this does not seem to answer the problem.  The extension needs to take action on behalf of the user.  We use it for things like creating pull requests for the user and pre-filling data but we want the action to be taken as the user, not some automated application that would remove accountability.

Additionally, this still seems to have either login frequency or security issues with token persistence on the client machine in user space.

@AJHenderson PAT is not suitable for your situation. If you cannot accept the third option, you can choose the second option. However, I remember that the token duration of the third option seems to be one hour, which should not be too long. :)
